# Adding search to "Theme.Holo.Light" ActionBar in android studio

Tags: java, android, list

I am trying to add search function to my todo list. I was able to add it successfully when using "Theme.AppCompact.Light" however, when I changed my theme to "Theme.Holo.Light" so that I could display the app's icon as the back button, all my other icons go to the menu drop down list including the search and this disables the search function. Is there a different way of doing it?

Below is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

Below is my menu_main.xml file:

```
     <item
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:title="@string/menu_search_title"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:title="@string/menu_add_title"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_exit"
        android:title="@string/menu_exit"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"/>
```

Inflating the menu:

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: you have to change app: to android: